# Month-over-month Customer Retention Rate in R

Tags: r

I am attempting to come up with a way of calculating month-over-month customer retention rate with a large data set of 390k rows. Basically, I want to know the percentage of customers present in a month that were also present in the previous month.

So if last month, customers a, b, and c purchased a product. And this month, customers b, c, and d made a purchase. Two of the three customers from last month made a purchase this month. Notice that d did not purchase last month so it is excluded from consideration this month, but next month it will be considered.

I have a simple but representative data frame below.

```
year_mon = c("2018 Nov", "2018 Nov", "2018 Nov", "2018 Nov", "2018 Nov", "2018 Dec", "2018 Dec", "2018 Dec", "2019 Jan", "2019 Jan", "2019 Feb", "2019 Feb", "2019 Feb")

customer_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3)

data.frame(customer_id, year_mon)
```

How could I calculate CRR no matter how many months I would have? That is to say, I don't want this hard coded. If I have 30 consecutive months of data or 3 months of consecutive data, I would like a solution that calculates CRR.

From https://www.bitrix24.com/glossary/what-is-customer-retention-rate-definition.php:

Customer Retention Rate = ((EC-NC)/SC)*100, where:

- EC - number of customers at the end of a period
- NC - number of new customers during that period
- SC - number of customers at the start of that period

Let's say you released a mobile game. On September 1st you had 1000 players. You got 500 new players by September 30, however 200 players stopped playing the game. So, at the end of a period (in our case one month) you had 1300 playing customers. Let's calculate the retention rate:

```
((1300-500)/1000)*100=80
```

So, you manage to retain 80% of your customers. Each industry has their own "good" and "bad" retention rates. Needless to say, every company tries to retain maximum percentage of customers.

**EDIT** @r2evans here the solution you offered seems to have "reset" for January of both years oddly enough. I verified that there are customers present in December also in January, so the CRR should not have been zero. I'm wondering if there is any explanation that can account for this.

[image: image of output showing 0% CRR for Jan of both years]

Comment: Are your dates really formatted like that? They are neither consistent (`"%b %Y"` and `"%Y %b"`) nor sortable (`"2018 Dec"` comes *before* `"2018 Nov"`). Is there a reason you have not made that column a `Date` class?

Comment: is your representative data frame supposed to have different date formats? `2018 Dec` &  `Dec 2018`

Comment: what is customer retention rate?

Comment: @r2evans I corrected the date formatting.

Comment: I know how the code that solves this problem, but I do not understand how you can calculate a month over month CRR with this data, since it is not clear to me how you set SC and EC. Can you please modify you CRR example to use the data from your `data.frame`? Thank you!

Comment: @MacOS I think that's part of my issue. I was thinking that a solution would involve identifying the amount of customer IDs present in the current month that was also present in the previous month using something like customers_this_month %in% customers_last_month

Comment: I understand. But this seems to be an issue that is not related to programming, because it is one step before you write code. I can therefore not provide you with a correct solution. The maximum I can do is to give you an approximation (i.e. how I would do it).

Comment: @MacOS in the interest of making Stackoverflow a useful repository of information for future users, I think your approximated method would still be helpful to post as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to look at it:

```r
dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(
    Date = as.Date(paste0(dat$year_mon, "01"), format = "%Y %b %d")
  ) %>%
  select(-year_mon) %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  group_by(customer_id) %>%
  mutate(
    stayed = c(FALSE, diff(as.POSIXlt(Date)$mon) %in% c(1L, -11L)),
    notnew = c(FALSE, rep(TRUE, n() - 1))
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
dat2
# # A tibble: 13 x 4
#    customer_id Date       stayed notnew
#          <dbl> <date>     <lgl>  <lgl> 
#  1           1 2018-11-01 FALSE  FALSE 
#  2           2 2018-11-01 FALSE  FALSE 
#  3           3 2018-11-01 FALSE  FALSE 
#  4           4 2018-11-01 FALSE  FALSE 
#  5           5 2018-11-01 FALSE  FALSE 
#  6           2 2018-12-01 TRUE   TRUE  
#  7           3 2018-12-01 TRUE   TRUE  
#  8           4 2018-12-01 TRUE   TRUE  
#  9           3 2019-01-01 TRUE   TRUE  
# 10           4 2019-01-01 TRUE   TRUE  
# 11           1 2019-02-01 FALSE  TRUE  
# 12           2 2019-02-01 FALSE  TRUE  
# 13           3 2019-02-01 TRUE   TRUE
```

This tells us: if a customer has had continued service from last month into this month, and if not, if they are not new (i.e., gapped 1 or more months).

For instance ...

```r
dat2 %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarize(
    n_customers = n(),
    n_stayed = sum(stayed),
    n_new = sum(!notnew),
    n_returned = sum(notnew)
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    prev_n_customer = lag(n_customers),
    CRR = 100 * n_stayed / prev_n_customer
  )
# # A tibble: 4 x 7
#   Date       n_customers n_stayed n_new n_returned prev_n_customer   CRR
#   <date>           <int>    <int> <int>      <int>           <int> <dbl>
# 1 2018-11-01           5        0     5          0              NA  NA  
# 2 2018-12-01           3        3     0          3               5  60  
# 3 2019-01-01           2        2     0          2               3  66.7
# 4 2019-02-01           3        1     0          3               2  50
```

Given the data that you provided, I suspect the CRR is correct. (This flow assumes that the data you have is month-continuous with no gaps in data. If this `dat2` could have a gapped month that is not in the data at all, then we need to modify the `lag(...)` logic into a self-join. Perhaps minor, I thought it unlikely if you have "solid" data.)

**Updated** to fix Dec-to-Jan transitions (that were previously resetting).

---

Data:

```r
year_mon = c("2018 Nov", "2018 Nov", "2018 Nov", "2018 Nov", "2018 Nov", "2018 Dec", "2018 Dec", "2018 Dec", "2019 Jan", "2019 Jan", "2019 Feb", "2019 Feb", "2019 Feb")
customer_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3)
dat <- data.frame(customer_id, year_mon)
```

Comment: thanks for your response it seems to work well but I do have a question. I have edited my answer to include a screenshot of output once I applied your solution to my data and I notice that in January of each year the retention rate is 0. For some reason, it seems that each year things are "resetting." I subsetted the list of customers from December and also January and using "%in%" verified that there indeed are some overlap minimally. Do you know of any reason why the solution would "reset" at the beginning of each year? See screenshot.

Comment: I see, yes. (1) Images of data are bad, in general I don't try to transcribe. That image is even worse, low quality, hard to read. No need to replace it now, but text is much much better. (2) Yes, the problem is that I just just `diff(...) == 1`. Change it to `diff(...) %in% c(1L, -11L)`. See my edit.