# How to calculate yearly retention rate by group in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a large data set with individuals located in counties over a period of multiple years. Each year, some individuals move to a different county or leave the data set and new individuals join.
I would like to count the number of individuals that stayed in the same county from year to year and from year 1. Here is the question I found that comes closest to this task (without the additional grouping by counties): [Month-over-month Customer Retention Rate in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61893777/month-over-month-customer-retention-rate-in-r)

Here is a simplified version of the data set:

```
dt <- setDT(data.frame(ID = rep(c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'e', 'f'),2),
                 CTY = rep(c(1, 2), each = 11),
                 YEAR = rep(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3),2)))
```

My solution, so far, relies on a loop

```
x =matrix(NA, 2,3)
y =matrix(NA, 2,3)
for (i in 1:2) {
  for (j in 1:3) {
    x[i,j] = ifelse(j == 1, NA, sum(dt[CTY == i & YEAR == j, ID] %in%  dt[CTY == i & YEAR == j-1, ID] == T))
    y[i,j] = ifelse(j == 1, NA, sum(dt[CTY == i & YEAR == 1, ID] %in%  dt[CTY == i & YEAR == j, ID] == T))
  }
}
```

Which gives after joining

```
colnames(x) <- unique(dt$YEAR)
rownames(x) <- unique(dt$CTY)
x <- reshape2::melt(x)
names(x) <- c("CTY", "YEAR", "stayed")
x <- x[order(x$CTY),]

colnames(y) <- unique(dt$YEAR)
rownames(y) <- unique(dt$CTY)
y <- reshape2::melt(y)
names(y) <- c("CTY", "YEAR", "stayed2")
y <- y[order(y$CTY),]

dt <-dt[x, on = c("CTY", "YEAR")]
dt <-dt[y, on = c("CTY", "YEAR")]

dt

#     ID CTY YEAR stayed stayed2
#  1:  a   1    1     NA      NA
#  2:  b   1    1     NA      NA
#  3:  c   1    1     NA      NA
#  4:  d   1    1     NA      NA
#  5:  a   1    2      3       3
#  6:  c   1    2      3       3
#  7:  d   1    2      3       3
#  8:  e   1    2      3       3
#  9:  c   1    3      2       1
# 10:  e   1    3      2       1
# 11:  f   1    3      2       1
# 12:  a   2    1     NA      NA
# 13:  b   2    1     NA      NA
# 14:  c   2    1     NA      NA
# 15:  d   2    1     NA      NA
# 16:  a   2    2      3       3
# 17:  c   2    2      3       3
# 18:  d   2    2      3       3
# 19:  e   2    2      3       3
# 20:  c   2    3      2       1
# 21:  e   2    3      2       1
# 22:  f   2    3      2       1
```

This is the right final table but it requires manipulation of the loop output  that seems unnecessary; in sum, this works but it is clunky and slow.
I have experimented with data.table and dplyr solutions but can't seem to make it work.

Comment: Not getting the expected output based on your loop code

Comment: It would help if you would describe the calculation you're attempting in a little more detail.  Is `stayed` the year on year retention and `stayed2` stayed since the beginning? And although your output is still at the `ID` level, the metrics are calculated at the`CTY:YEAR` level, right? And perhaps you could edit your sample data so that the expected result for `stayed` is different from `stayed2` - if the logic is supposed to be different but the result is supposed to be the same, it's harder to test effectively.

Comment: @GregorThomas your interpretation is correct. Just edited to change the results for stayed and stayed2.

Comment: @AndreC is the expected output correct

Comment: @akrun it is correct. I realize the wording is not clear on that. I will edit.

Comment: I was thinking more in `dt[, ID_lag := shift(ID), .(CTY, YEAR)]` and then get the length of interesect of ID_lag and ID for each CTY, YEAR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `sapply` function like this:

```
fx <- function(x) ifelse(x$YEAR == 1, NA, sum(dt[CTY == x$CTY & YEAR == x$YEAR, ID] %in%  dt[CTY == x$CTY & YEAR == x$YEAR-1, ID] == T))
fy <- function(y) ifelse(y$YEAR == 1, NA, sum(dt[CTY == y$CTY & YEAR == 1, ID] %in%  dt[CTY == y$CTY & YEAR == y$YEAR, ID] == T))

x <- merge(data.frame(CTY=1:2),data.frame(YEAR=1:3))
s <- data.frame(x,stayed=sapply(split(x,1:nrow(x)),fx))
s <- data.frame(s,stayed2=sapply(split(x,1:nrow(x)),fy))
    
merge(dt,s)

#     CTY YEAR ID stayed stayed2
#  1:   1    1  a     NA      NA
#  2:   1    1  b     NA      NA
#  3:   1    1  c     NA      NA
#  4:   1    1  d     NA      NA
#  5:   1    2  a      3       3
#  6:   1    2  c      3       3
#  7:   1    2  d      3       3
#  8:   1    2  e      3       3
#  9:   1    3  c      2       1
# 10:   1    3  e      2       1
# 11:   1    3  f      2       1
# 12:   2    1  a     NA      NA
# 13:   2    1  b     NA      NA
# 14:   2    1  c     NA      NA
# 15:   2    1  d     NA      NA
# 16:   2    2  a      3       3
# 17:   2    2  c      3       3
# 18:   2    2  d      3       3
# 19:   2    2  e      3       3
# 20:   2    3  c      2       1
# 21:   2    3  e      2       1
# 22:   2    3  f      2       1
```