# Replicate R Solution in Python for Calculating Monthly CRR

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr

New to this, but trying to find a way to replicate this excellent solution from [@r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3358272/r2evans) in Python: [Month-over-month Customer Retention Rate in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61893777/month-over-month-customer-retention-rate-in-r)

Here is the solution for calculating monthly customer retention rate (CRR):

```
# data
year_mon = c("2018 Nov", "2018 Nov", "2018 Nov", "2018 Nov", "2018 Nov", "2018 Dec", "2018 Dec", "2018 Dec", "2019 Jan", "2019 Jan", "2019 Feb", "2019 Feb", "2019 Feb")

customer_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3)

dat <- data.frame(customer_id, year_mon)

# code
dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(
    Date = as.Date(paste0(dat$year_mon, "01"), format = "%Y %b %d")
  ) %>%
  select(-year_mon) %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  group_by(customer_id) %>%
  mutate(
    stayed = c(FALSE, diff(as.POSIXlt(Date)$mon) %in% c(1L, -11L)),
    notnew = c(FALSE, rep(TRUE, n() - 1))
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
dat2
```

Example of using the solution to generate CRR calcs:

```
dat2 %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarize(
    n_customers = n(),
    n_stayed = sum(stayed),
    n_new = sum(!notnew),
    n_returned = sum(notnew)
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    prev_n_customer = lag(n_customers),
    CRR = 100 * n_stayed / prev_n_customer
  )
```

Comment: No need to repeat the R code, as you can link to it. Rather, create an example DataFrame (in code) and the expected results, so that somebody writing an answer can test it. Start porting the code to Pandas - where do you get stuck?

Comment: Thanks. Basically, I am trying to create a Python script as an exact (or as close as possible) replica of the R code, hence copy/paste. So, with the same data, running in R or Python will give the same results in the same form (data frame/tibble, etc.). But in particular, per your question, I am getting stuck at this bit in the first code chunk: mutate(
    stayed = c(FALSE, diff(as.POSIXlt(Date)$mon) %in% c(1L, -11L)),
    notnew = c(FALSE, rep(TRUE, n() - 1))
  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) v0.6.3+, it is able to replicate this in python:

```py
>>> from datar.all import (
...     c, f, tibble, mutate, select, ungroup, summarize, lag, as_date,
...     diff, sum, paste, arrange, group_by, pd_dt, rep, n, is_in,
... )
>>> 
>>> year_mon = c(
...     "2018 Nov", "2018 Nov", "2018 Nov", "2018 Nov", "2018 Nov",
...     "2018 Dec", "2018 Dec", "2018 Dec", "2019 Jan", "2019 Jan",
...     "2019 Feb", "2019 Feb", "2019 Feb",
... )
>>> customer_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3)
>>> 
>>> dat = tibble(year_mon=year_mon, customer_id=customer_id)
>>> dat2 = (
...     dat
...     >> mutate(Date=as_date(paste(f.year_mon, "01"), format="%Y %b %d"))
...     >> select(~f.year_mon)
...     >> arrange(f.Date)
...     >> group_by(f.customer_id)
...     >> mutate(
...         stayed=c(False, is_in(diff(pd_dt(f.Date).month), c(1, -11))),
...         notnew=c(False, rep(True, n() - 1)),
...     )
...     >> ungroup()
... )
>>> 
>>> dat2
    customer_id             Date    stayed    notnew
        <int64> <datetime64[ns]> <boolean> <boolean>
0             1       2018-11-01     False     False
1             2       2018-11-01     False     False
2             3       2018-11-01     False     False
3             4       2018-11-01     False     False
4             5       2018-11-01     False     False
5             2       2018-12-01      True      True
6             3       2018-12-01      True      True
7             4       2018-12-01      True      True
8             3       2019-01-01      True      True
9             4       2019-01-01      True      True
10            1       2019-02-01     False      True
11            2       2019-02-01     False      True
12            3       2019-02-01      True      True
>>> 
>>> (
...     dat2
...     >> group_by(f.Date)
...     >> summarize(
...         n_customers=n(),
...         n_stayed=sum(f.stayed),
...         n_new=sum(~f.notnew),
...         n_returned=sum(f.notnew),
...     )
...     >> mutate(
...         prev_n_customer=lag(f.n_customers),
...         CRR=100 * f.n_stayed / f.prev_n_customer,
...     )
... )
              Date  n_customers  n_stayed   n_new  n_returned  prev_n_customer        CRR
  <datetime64[ns]>      <int64>   <Int64> <Int64>     <Int64>        <float64>  <Float64>
0       2018-11-01            5         0       5           0              NaN        NaN
1       2018-12-01            3         3       0           3              5.0       60.0
2       2019-01-01            2         2       0           2              3.0  66.666667
3       2019-02-01            3         1       0           3              2.0       50.0
```

Comment: @pdw5 Please consider picking it as the answer if it solves your problem.